# Navigating to the updated page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

When I insert data  from other page and pop this page to go back on the listing page, I have to refresh the listing page to get the updated list of data. I want to go back to the updated version of page without pressing refresh button. I am using pushNamed and also I want to have a back arrow button on the input page.

Comment: after getting the data from page, do setState to update ui with latest data

Answer (score 0):

Using `Navigator.push` or `Navigator.pushNamed` returns a `Future` object to you.
This `Future` resolves when you use `Navigator.pop` in the your second screen.

Here is a basic example. Assuming you have function `goToNewPage` which you are calling to push a new Screen, you can do it like this.

```
class Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {

  void goToNewPage (context) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('screen2').then((_) {
       // The screen2 has popped. so you can just call setState here to just rebuild
       // You can do anything you want here, that needs to happen after the new page has been popped. 
       setState(() {});
    });
  }   

  ... rest of your code.
```

Note, the actual implementation of what you should do inside the `callback` depends on how your widget is getting data. But you can do anything you want to do after your new page is popped inside that `callback`.